# Is my extension crashing Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, crash

I've developed an extension for Google Chrome. It does some cross-domain httprequests, messaging and inserts an iframe into web pages.

After testing it without any problems on Linux, Mac and Windows (XP and 7), I installed it on a colleague's Windows XP pc. After opening 2 or 3 pages, Chrome crashed with the Dutch equivalent of the "Aw, Snap!" page.

After that it kept crashing regularly. Restarting Chrome didn't help. Even after removing the extension it crashed occasionally, though not as often. the colleague says Chrome has never crashed on him before, but then again, he hardly ever uses it.

When running chrome from the command-line with logging enabled, I see the following message:

[1744:628:0703/101212:ERROR:gpu_info_collector_win.cc(98)] Can't retrieve a valid WinSAT assessment.

[4744:4272:0703/090810:ERROR:textfield.h(162)] NOT IMPLEMENTED

Could this be caused (or exacerbated) by my extension? How can I be sure that this is just a one-of and will not crash the browsers of a lot of other users?

Thanks in advance for any help or insights.

Jerry.

Comment: 1. Chrome version? 2. Try to create a minimal extension which reproduces the problem, and post the source code here. 3. http://crbug.com/

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. 1. Chrome version: 28.0.1500.63 m. 2. I'll try, though the crash doesn't happen every time and it even sometimes crashes without the extension installed.

Comment: If it crashes without installing the extension, the answer is clear, right? Try re-installing Chrome and see if the problems go away.

Comment: You're right. I'm probably being paranoid. It's just that it started crashing right after installation of the extension. But the crashes kept happening -less frequently- after removing the extension again.I'll try to re-install Chrome and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your application files are corrupted. App files contain important settings, configurations which you need to be restored again.

Click the Start button, select Run. Type the below path and press ENTER:

`C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data`

Delete all the files present in this directory and restart Google Chrome. More solutions [here](http://chromecrashes.com/).